# C# and SQL Server 2005: Return value and update in one batch

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

Just curious whether it is reliable way to do following: I need to get some value and then update it, optimally in one batch.

```
SELECT X FROM Y //will it be returned if executed in one batch?
UPDATE Y SET X...
```

Executed as Reader? I am not sure whether it will return if there is the UPDATE statetement. And one extra question, what if I needed to return true or false (or any other pair of values) depending on whether or notsome statement succeed?

Comment: It'll be easier to give an answer if you show the specific SQL you want to execute, or a redacted example of it, rather than pseudo code. Also, what database server are you targeting? Oracle, Sql Server, MySql? =)

Comment: Do you want to return data that you've previously updated or that have been updated? Or just any other data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. If the question is about how to update and select in one statement than see gbn's answer.

If the question is about how to execute two different statements, than you can use begin-end block:

```
begin

  select * from x

  update y set a = ...

end
```

You can set CommandType to text and use `ExecuteReader` method of the command. Both statements will be executed and you will get result set from the select statement.

Comment: One question: why to use being-end block? I cannot see any difference. Its only to make it "atomic"?

Comment: Yes, it is to make it atomic. Also I'm not sure that it would work without begin/end block (but maybe I'm confusing it with some other database).

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Y
OUTPUT --use this
SET X...
```

The [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(SQL.90).aspx) clause allows this for SQL Server 2005+ (I'm guessing with c#)